# Differentiate the Function: $f(x)=(x^3+2x)e^x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)=(x^3+2x)e^x$ by looking at it I would assume I should use the product rule. Thus,

$f'=x^3+2x\cdot e^x+e^x\cdot (3x)(2)$

$f'=x^3+2x\cdot e^x +e^x\cdot 6x$

However, this is not the answer according to the book.

Comment: $g(x)=x^3+2x$, $h(x)=e^x$, $f(x)=g(x) \cdot h(x)$. Thus $f'= g' \cdot h + g \cdot h'= (3 x^2 +2) e^x+ (x^3+2x) e^x= (x^3+ 3x^2+ 2x +2)e^x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To differentiate this we must use the product rule which is as follows:
$$\frac{d}{dx} (u\cdot v) = u'\cdot v + v'\cdot u$$
Here $u = x^3+2x$ and $v = e^x$. That means $u'$ is $3x^2+2$ (using the power rule) and $v'$ is $e^x$.

We now have:
$$\frac{d}{dx} (x^3+2x)(e^x)$$
$$=\boxed {(3x^2 +2)(e^x) + (x^3+2x)(e^x)}$$

We can use this answer or we can simplify further by factoring out $e^x$:
$$= {(3x^2 +2)(e^x) + (x^3+2x)(e^x)}$$
$$=(e^x)(3x^2+2+x^3+2x)$$
$$=\boxed{e^x(x^3+3x^2+2x+2)}$$

Answer (score 2):

To differentiate the function, we use the product rule. So we get $$f'(x) = (x^3 + 2x)(e^x)' + (e^x)(x^3 + 2x)'$$

Which then simplifies to $$f'(x) = e^x(x^3 + 2x) + e^x(3x^2 + 2)$$

Remember, the product rule is being used on $(x^3 + 2x)$ (the whole bracket) and $e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $$ f(x) = ( x^3 + 2 x ) e^x$$

Then we get

$$ f'(x) = ( 3 x^2 + 2 ) e^x + ( x^3 + 2 x) e^x $$

or

$$ f'(x) = ( x^3 + 3 x^2 + 2 x + 2 ) e^x $$

Answer (score 0):

Try: $f' = (x^3 +2x)(e^x) + (e^x)(3x^2 +2) = (e^x)(x^3+3x^2 + 2x +2)$

The derivative of $x^3 + 2x$ is $3x^2+2$

Answer (score 0):

${\left ((x^3+2x)e^x  \right )}' = (3x^2+2)e^x + (x^3+2x)e^x = e^x(x^3+3x^2+2x+2).$